# Returning original post data if request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, listener, response

I know I could just do this with a global, but I'd like to be object oriented if I can. If my request response returns a false for that 'ok' value, I'd like to log the data that was originally posted. Is that data accessible by a listener function on the request object?
Thanks!

```
function reqListener () {
        var data = this.responseText;
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jsonResponse['ok'] == false) {
            //Here I want to log the data that I originally posted
            console.log(__TheFormDataThatWasPassedtoSend__);
        }
    }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load",reqListener);
    xhr.open('POST',urltopostto, true);

    // Set up a handler for when the request finishes.
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // File(s) uploaded.
        console.log('Uploaded');
      } else {
        alert('An error occurred!');
      }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem you have is needing to use data known when you create the eventListener when the eventListener actually fires. Below is your code to do this with `formData`

```
function reqListener (formData) {
        var data = this.responseText;
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jsonResponse['ok'] == false) {
            console.log(formData);
        }
    }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { reqListener.call(this,formData) });
    xhr.open('POST',urltopostto, true);

    // Set up a handler for when the request finishes.
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // File(s) uploaded.
        console.log('Uploaded');
      } else {
        alert('An error occurred!');
      }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
```